# Using the container inside a simple bundle class in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a simple class inside my bundle in Symfony 2:

```
class MyTest {
    public function myFunction() {
        $logger = $this->get('logger');
        $logger->err('testing out');
    }
}
```

How can i access the container?

Comment: check [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) and use @container

Comment: This article teaches how to create a service that can be called by a controller, not how to call a service from inside my class.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services

Comment: In most cases you should be injecting only the services you need, not the entire service container.

Comment: @simshaun you're right, and in most cases, a class needing a service (like the famous service container) should be a service.

Comment: It is a service, used to override the kernel event for exception.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to inject the service container. Your class will be look this:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class MyTest
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function myFunction()
    {
        $logger = $this->container->get('logger');
        $logger->err('testing out');
    }
}
```

Then within a controller or a ContainerAware instance:

```
$myinstance = new MyTest($this->container);
```

If you need more explanations: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: I can't inject the container because the class i'm creating is kernel event listener. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-exception-event

Comment: Injectding the whole container is a bad idea in almost all cases.

Comment: @vinnylinux: event listeners can be registered as service

Answer (score 7):

Injecting the whole container is a bad idea in most cases. Inject the needed services individually.

```
namespace Vendor;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface;

class MyTest 
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) 
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function myFunction() 
    {
        $logger->err('testing out');
    }
}
```

Register the service in `services.yml`:

```
services:
    my_test:
        class: Vendor\MyTest
        arguments: [@logger]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not add `@logger` service only? e.g

```
arguments: [@logger]
```

If you want to add container (WHICH IS NOT RECOMMENDED), then you can add `@service_container` in `services.yml`.

Comment: Try adding [custom logging channel](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#using-a-custom-logging-channel-with-monolog).